# Input field with type number validation not working

Tags: angularjs, validation

Here is my code, I am trying to validated my input but validations not working

```
<form class="form-horizontal m-t-n" role="form">
 <div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-sm-4">
      <div class="input-group">
        <h3>{{ 'Select Quantity (max 5)' | translate }}</h3>
        <input type="number" name="quantity" ng-model="quantity" ng- change="setQuantity(quantity)" value="1"class="form-control" placeholder="{{ 'Quantity' | translate }}" ng-required integer >
      </div>
    </div>
 </div>     
</form><br>

Here is my setQuantity function:

$scope.setQuantity = function setQuantity( quantity ) {
    $scope.quantity = quantity;
}
```

Comment: which browser are you using ?

Comment: Can you be more specific as to what isn't working?

Comment: @AdityaBhave I am using google chrome

Comment: @Bucket ng-required integer and min, max validations are not working

Comment: Have you put your `input` field inside a `form` tag ?

Answer (score 1):

You can check the validity manually using `ng-form` and `$valid` property. Make sure to give `name` to every field inside `ng-form` and access the field in controller using `frmName[fieldName]`.

```js
var app = angular.module('mainApp', []);
app.controller('MyController', ['$scope', function($scope) {
  $scope.setQuantity = function setQuantity(quantity) {
    let isValid = $scope.myFrm['quantity'].$valid;
    if (quantity && isValid) {
      $scope.quantity = quantity;
    }

    console.log(quantity, isValid);
  }
}]);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.7.5/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="mainApp">
  <div ng-controller="MyController">
    <ng-form class="form-horizontal m-t-n" name="myFrm">
      <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-sm-4">
          <div class="input-group">
            <h3>{{ 'Select Quantity (max 5)' }}</h3>
            <input type="number" name="quantity" ng-model="quantity" ng-change="setQuantity(quantity)" value="1" class="form-control" placeholder="{{ 'Quantity' }}" max="5" min="1" ng-required> </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </ng-form>
  </div>
</div>
```

Make sure that the `input` field is inside a `form` tag. Also, you can simply use `required` `html` attribute instead of ng-required. Check below code.

```html
<form>
  <input type="number" name="quantity" ng-model="quantity"
       ng-change="setQuantity(quantity)" min="1" max="5" value="1"
       class="form-control" placeholder="{{ 'Quantity' | translate }}"
       required integer>
  
  <br><br>
  
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

If you Must use angular-js then keep `ng-required`, make sure to put the code inside `ng-app`

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.7.5/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="">
  <form>
    <input type="number" name="quantity" ng-model="quantity"
         ng-change="setQuantity(quantity)" min="1" max="5" value="1"
         class="form-control" placeholder="{{ 'Quantity' }}"
         ng-required integer>

    <br><br>

    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
  </form>
</div>
```

Comment: It still not working if I give min max than value which is selected isn't display on next page & i don't have submit button for the form.

Comment: Can you please provide more code and exact functionality that you are trying to achieve ?

Comment: It still not working min, max and I am trying to validated my phone number using ng-minlength and ng-maxlength both didn't worrk for me @Aditya

Comment: For phone number use `input` with `type="text"` not `type="number"`

Comment: I have used this for phone number` <input type="tel" name="phone" ng-model="phone" ng-required="true" placeholder="{{ 'Phone Number without Country Code' | translate }}" class="form-control" ng-minlength="phone_min_length" ng-maxlength="phone_max_length" numbers-only>`

Comment: You can try using the `html pattern` validator. `<input type="tel" name="phone" pattern="[0-9]{10}" required>`. If you want to use `angular validators` only then you can use `ng-pattern="[0-9]{10}"`

Comment: I am not able to validate it in quantity, even I am able to enter negative number in it, it not restrict negative number and the min max values though.

Comment: I have solved that issue by writing custom validation.Thanks all for the help